# Google Maps don't work sometimes... Or almost always not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

Well, Simply failed to understand why it does not work Google Maps.
I read almost all the documentation, not only for the problems I have, but it also because I needed to use polygons, among others.

**So, this is my code(*I put some comments so that they can understand more quickly*):**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<div style="width:100%;height:400px;padding:0;margin:0;">
    <div id="canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function initialize() {
        var colors = ['#00bfff','#7eabe9','#799fe7','#7293e5','#6989e4','#5e7ee3','#5273e2','#4169e1','#4b6fde','#5274db','#5979d8','#5f7fd5','#6584d2','#698acf','#1e90ff'];
        var location = [
            {"name":"lisboa","lat":38.725717,"lng":-9.150248},
            {"name":"madrid","lat":40.420275,"lng":-3.705766},
            {"name":"burdeos","lat":44.836625,"lng":-0.581048},
            {"name":"loira","lat":46.621773,"lng":2.452032},
            {"name":"paris","lat":48.856929,"lng":2.341198},
            {"name":"bruselas","lat":50.848375,"lng":4.349679},
            {"name":"rotterdam","lat":51.922848,"lng":4.478452},
            {"name":"amsterdam","lat":52.373085,"lng":4.893276}
        ];
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
            'center'    :   new google.maps.LatLng(0,-180),
            'zoom'      :   3,
            'mapTypeId' :   google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });

        // store positions on var flightPlanCoordinates
        var flightPlanCoordinates = [];

        // set markers and popovers/infWindow
        // *remember var flightPlanCoordinates*
        for (var i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
            var lat     =   location[i].lat,
                lng     =   location[i].lng,
                name    =   location[i].name;
            var pos     =   new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                'content'   :   name,
                'map'       :   map,
                'position'  :   pos
            });
            infowindow.close();
            flightPlanCoordinates.push(pos);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                'position'  :   pos,
                'map'       :   map,
                'title'     :   name,
                'icon'      :   {
                    'path'      :   google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    'scale'     :   5,
                    'strokeColor':  colors[i]
                }
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                if (infowindow) {
                    infowindow.close();
                }
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
        // set polylines
        // *remember var flightPlanCoordinates*
        for (var i = 0; i < flightPlanCoordinates.length; i++) {
            if(typeof flightPlanCoordinates[i+1] == 'undefined'){
                continue;
            }
            var PathStyle = new google.maps.Polyline({
                'path'          : [
                    flightPlanCoordinates[i],
                    flightPlanCoordinates[i+1]
                ],
                'strokeColor'   : colors[i],
                'strokeOpacity' : 1.0,
                'strokeWeight'  : 2,
                'map'           : map
            });
        }
    }
    // Draw Google Maps V3
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

The page/site have UTF-8 without BOM Charset via document and server(apache force UTF-8 and the HTML is write in UTF-8 without BOM).

**Well, right now Look what I see(*Each of the images is a snapshot to refresh the page*):**

> Sometimes work fine, sometimes...

[image]

> Anothertimes, work, work bad, very bad...

[image]

> Anothertimes, work, work bad, very bad and show parts o cuts parts...

[image]
[image]
[image]

> I also tested this in the following browsers:

- iPad Air 2, iOS 8.1 - Google Chrome 44.0.2403.67
- iPad Air 2, iOS 8.1 - Safari
- MacBook Air, yosemite - Google Chrome
- MacBook Air, yosemite - Safari
- MacBook Air, yosemite - Firefox
- Windows 8 - Google Chrome with disable Adblock
- Windows 8 - Firefox
- Windows 8 - Safari
- Windows 8 - Internet Explorer 8, 9, 10
- Android 4.4.4, Xiaomi MI4 - Google Chrome Android
- Android 4.4.4, Xiaomi MI4 - Firefox Android
- Window Phone 8.10 - Internet Explorer
- Firefox OS 1.1.0.0 - Internet Explorer

> Here code snippet
>    - http://jsbin.com/fozocimuke/edit?html,js,output
>    - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNoGVN

Please, help me... I don't understand whats happend here...
Thanks.

Comment: I tried to put your code into a fiddle - but I couldn't get any map to load - and no errors. Could you create one, or a Stack Snippet? Or give us the link to this on the web. I've had this issue before - seeing it in context will help me confirm

Comment: yes, but jsfiddle dont work fine, here have http://jsbin.com/fozocimuke/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You get the same issue on all browsers?

Comment: Yes, all browser... And differents OS... iOS, Windows, Android, Ubuntu, etc... i dont understand... i test this code on another computers, i have same problems, but on particular computer(with same characteristics, a simple windows 8 pc with 4gm ram, for example...) i dont have problem...  i dont understand... I'm very confused.

Comment: I had this issue with a Google Map housed within an accordion. The problem seemed to be that the map was loading incorrect map tiles based around the centre of the view. Wrap the init call in a jQuery `$(document).ready()` call

Comment: Tell me, Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox browser or some throws you a clue(console)?
In my case, I'm not using any accordion.

Comment: No clues from the console. What was happening with the accordion was that the height of the map was 0 when it was initialised. so when you would expand the accordion the same as in your images would happen. I'm guessing that by using `$(document).ready( function() { google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); })` you will be able to execute the initialisation after the browser has set up the page and css rules. The reason why you are getting the issue might be that the containing div's height has not be set until the map is initialised.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6221b6x2/), don't see any issues.

Comment: Well, thanks @DavidAnderton for you help, i found a solution.

Comment: awesome @OlafErlandsen - if you think its useful post your solution as an answer to your question :). Seems like a similar issue to what I had - I just couldn't remember the full solution

Comment: Hi Olaf I went ahead an put your answer as a response to this question so that it is shown as having an answer. You have the option to mark it as correct, but at least people will now see there has been a resolution here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

below answer was edited out of OlafErlandsen's question to stay true to Q&A format of SO. Upvote his question if below is useful

---

> Well, my canvas element(div#canvas) have 0px height on start
>   page(onload event), so, the solution is simple: need responsive map
>   becausse Google Maps by default no is responsive.
>
> Google Maps Api have multiples handlers and methods to help in this
>   case, for example:
>
> **google.maps.event.trigger()**
>
> **google.maps.event.addDomListener()**

So, if you need "enable" responsive maps, you need this code:

```
// you need the "map" var and this has to be a "map" (new google.maps.Map(...))
var map = ...;
// And you need
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    map.setCenter(center);
});
// And aditionally you can need use "trigger" for real responsive
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

> And, if you use accordions like Bootstrap, jQuery, jQuery UI and
>   another libs, and Google maps present similars problems, you can use
>   `trigger`. "Remember and think in the case of "slide" effects of
>   jQuery."

Example on jQuery UI:

```
$("#accordion").bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
    // here you trigger
    // And remember "map" var, in this case we assume that it is a global variable.
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I got Solution for me, Use Below code of line to resolve the issue :

```
// you need to use "map" var name Example : var map = (new google.maps.Map(...));

setTimeout(function() { google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') }, 600);
```

Comment: Maybe this solution consumes too much "resources".
I think you need bind events like "resize", "load", ...